# Replacing a section of html with PHP

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm trying to replace a section of a template HTML file I have by using regular expressions in PHP.  so far I have this:

```
$docText = OLD_TEXT;
$text = NEW_TEXT;
$docText = preg_replace('#<div id="information">[<div>(?R)</div>]*</div>#i x U',
                         $text,
                         $docText,
                         1);

// Save file
```

At the moments it's not making any matches. The goal is to have it replace the entire outer div which means that it needs to know that all other s aren't the closing tag.

Comment: can you post an example of $text?

Comment: First question in weeks where it would at least be relevant, but nobody posts the stupid link. -- So, uhm. Does it have to be regex? Or are simpler suggestions allowed? -- Anyway, your syntax for `?R` and then enclosing it as character class is wrong. Where did you find that?

Comment: Simpler options are fine.  I originally tried DOMDocument but after that didn't work I decided to try working directly with the string.  Sorry if I was supposed to post a link. This is the first time that I've posted on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I 'm not sure to understand what you want but I think you're trying to do this:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="information">
            <div>Hi!</div>
        </div>
        <div id="otherInformation">Hi again!</div>
    </body>
</html>
HTML;

$replace = '<div id="newInformation">Bye!</div>';

$dom    = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$tmp     = $dom->createTextNode('{newContent}');

$xpath   = new DOMXPath($dom);

$divInformation = $xpath->query('//div[@id="information"]');
$divInformation->item(0)->parentNode->replaceChild($tmp, $divInformation->item(0));

$newHTML = str_replace('{newContent}', $replace, $dom->saveHTML());
var_dump($newHTML);
```

Can I ask why?

Comment: I'm trying to create a content management system.  So far I have my site copy the information in the tags and echo it into a textArea.  I then send this to the php page, which replaces the information area with the new information.  I feel like I might be reinventing the wheel, but it makes sense in my head.

Comment: So, how about persistence? I take it you use a database? Is this why you echo stuff in a `textarea`, to post and store it?

Comment: It's a couple months later and I just checked back on this post.  After a lot of work I finally got this to work thanks to Fy-; however, I've done another site since then, and I used a MYSQL database instead.  SO MUCH EASIER!  I was creating an entirely new file for each dynamic page by replacing some text in a template (I ask myself why now), but MYSQL makes it a lot easier to do this.  Oh well, all worked out well in the end.  Lesson learned.